# UI recommendation in Netbeans for a Maven web application

Tags: java, html, jquery-ui, netbeans, frontend

I've always been a backend C/C++ developer. Working on a Java project (Netbeans), and I am trying to figure out how to do the front-end/UI. While I am a pretty good back-end dev, I haven't really been keeping up with the latest and greatest in frameworks, etc. for the front-end.

The Java back-end component can communicate with JSON over websockets. I am trying to figure out what front-end framework I should use. I also don't want to recreate my project, and would just like to add to my current Maven web application project.

So what's the verdict? What's hip and cool these days? HTML5? JQueryUI? (are they even mutually exclusive?)

Should also mention that I just want to make a quick UI, b/c I am planning on handing off the task to another programmer for a "proper" front-end component later on. At the same time, I do want my version to be "decent". So, in a nutshell, I want something that is easy to use, but still capable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this a web app, Angular is getting popular and Bootstrap has been popular for a while. Use pre-built templates you can find for free or at a site like http://themeforest.net . Don't waste your time trying to code your own, unless its super simple.

You probably want to also think about how the backend will communicate with the front if you haven't already. For example, will it use Servlets, or a framework like Spring Roo? You can also build the front in a completely different language, like PHP, as PHP outsourcing is cheaper and easier to find than Java . PHP is a server side language like Java, but I'm talking about a situation where the website's backend communicates with the java backend via an API or sharing a DB. PHP has many MVC frameworks such as Symfony and Laravel.

Comment: Thx. I am in the process of checking out Angular.